# Git: Reverting commit and adding a comment

Tags: git

I'm new to git on the command line (macOS) and have been trying to make a commit with a comment, change it and commit with a comment again, revert it and add a comment, and finally push it to the main branch. The first few 2 steps and the last one I can do with no problems, but reverting and adding a comment is giving me this error:

```
error: option `mainline' expects a number greater than zero
```

These are the steps I have been doing:

```
git init
```

Adding some code:

```
nano example.java
```

Registering new repository wth remote:

```
git remote add origin [link to github repo]
```

Adding files to local commit:

```
git add example.java
```

Initial commit:

```
git commit -a -m  "First commit"
```

Editing code:

```
nano example.java
```

Adding and commiting again:

```
git add example.java
git commit -a -m "Second commit"
```

Reverting:

```
git revert HEAD -m "Reverting"
```

This always returns the error I mentioned above.

Maybe I should be using a different command for reverting and adding the comment? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `-m` stands for `mainline` not `message` in the `revert` command. See [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Revert options:**

`git revert HEAD` - revert with default message

`git revert HEAD -e` - revert and edit commit message

`-m` flag at `revert` command is not "message", check `git revert` docs for more details

**Other options (history overwriting):**

`git reset --soft HEAD` (undo last local commit and then you can commit again with new commit message)

`git commit -av --amend --status -C HEAD` (append to previous local commit with previous commit message)

`git commit -av --amend --status -c HEAD` (append to previous local commit with updating commit message)

If you pushed already to server, then:

a) modify local history, overwrite remote history. good if you have rights and understanding what you are doing, and you are the single developer who working on this branch.

b) just use revert without history overwriting. good if you are newbie or need to update some common or shared branches, like `master` or `develop`